# Android: graphics shape.intersects method. Is there an analog in android?

Tags: android, graphics, shapes, region, intersect

I want to find a way how to do in android such thing(things like I do using java.awt.Shape):

```
Shape shape = ...;

shape.intersects(left, top, width, height);
shape.contains(left, top, width, height);
```

Tried to consider android classes: Path, Shape... but didn't find anything. A little bit confused by all this android stuff.

Could you please, guys help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Android has the [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersect(android.graphics.Rect)) class that has methods to detect intersection.

This might help as well:

[How to use the Rect.intersect method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492166/how-to-use-the-rect-intersect-method)