# How to use the Rect.intersect method. 

Tags: android, canvas, intersect

Ive created a game where you move a rectangle and dodge other falling rectangles from the sky. Though everytime the rectangles intersect nothing happens.

`if(mSquare.intersect(jSquare)){
             canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);`
or

```
collision = mSquare.intersect(jSquare);
     if(collision==true){  canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
  }  this always returns false no matter where the rectangles are.......
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, the simplest would be to get the bounding `Rect` for each `Bitmap` and on each time step to check for a collision using `Rect.intersect()` method.

Something like this:

```
boolean collision = player.getRect().intersect(fallingObject.getRect());
```

Additionally there are many other (better) ways to do this, especially when dealing with objects that aren't rectangles and when you have lots of objects on the screen.  Check out [this post for a good discussion](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/collision-detection-algorithm-r754)

Also the book "Beginning Android Games" has a great chapter about collision detection and the book is well worth a read if you are considering writing a game.

Comment: Ive tried a bunch of things but nothing seems to work..... Here is how far i got but these methods dont work...  if (Rect.intersects(mSquare, mSquare)){
         canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY); }        .................                                                or.......... boolean collision = mSquare.intersect(jSquare); if (collision == true){ canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY); } The canvas never changes! please help im screwed.

Comment: `Rect.intersect` is **NOT** a static method, meaning it needs to be called on an instance of an object.  The correct way to check for an intersetction between two rectangles, lets call them `r1` and `r2` is to call the method like this: `r1. intersect(r2)`  **NOT** `Rect.intersect(r1,r2)`  see the android Rect docs for more information http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html

Comment: Alright that makes sense but ive tried that...Maybe I cant check for an intersection on a canvas...?

Comment: can you post an update to your question with what code you've tried and describe why it isn't working?

Comment: Alright. Thanks so much for the help man it means a lot foreals.

Comment: boolean collision = mSquare.intersect(jSquare);..................
  if(collision==true){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
   
  }

Comment: It should be working but it doesnt give me a true or false return

Comment: if(mSquare.intersect(jSquare)){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);} --also doesnt work

Comment: Try using Log messages to verify the data in the Rect objects

Comment: thanks You set me in the right direction ... took me forever but i found out that my stupid rectangle didnt follow this sizing ---left <= right and top <= bottom.