# Trouble with two imageviews collision detection [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android

I tried using this code which I found on a related question but it is still not working. Any thoughts? Thank you

```
Rect r1 = new Rect();
        imageView1.getDrawingRect(r1);

Rect r2 = new Rect();
        imageView2.getDrawingRect(r2);

        if(r1.intersect(r2)) {
            btn.setText("Collision");
        }
```

Comment: Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492166/how-to-use-the-rect-intersect-method

Comment: print out the values of r1 and r2. their sizes might be zero if you call the method before they are measured.